# In Prisma, how do I create a many-to-many relationship but one side of the relationship creates unique instances of the other side?

Tags: schema, data-modeling, database-schema, prisma

Let's say we are creating an LMS with Students and Exercises.

The Students have many exercises and each exercise has many users...BUT... I want to put a "isComplete Boolean?" on the exercise model and have each student be able to know if they completed that exercise or not.

I know this is a super simple problem, I have been banging my head and cannot for the life of me figure out how to model these!

```
model Student {
  name String
  exercises Exercise[]
}

model Exercise {
  title String
  description String

  isComplete Boolean @default(false)

  students Student[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That sounds to me like a use case for an explicit many-to-many relation: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#explicit-many-to-many-relations

You can then add this attribute to the third table that connects students with exercises.